# Populate the Diagonal Elements of An Array MATLAB

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, nested-loops, diagonal

I have the following matrix C that I would like to recreate in MATLAB:

[image]

In this case uppercase C is an N = 3 by N = 3 matrix, but I would like to generate C for any size of N by N.

I randomly create random values for c on the interval 1 to 20 using:

```
N = 3
c =  randi([1,20],N+1,1,"double");
```

I initially thought that I could use nested for loops as follows:

```
function C = carray(c,N)
    C = zeros(N,N)
    for i =1:1:N
        for j=1:1:N
            if isdiag(C(i,j))
                C(i,j) = c(i) + c(i+1)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

However, this does not produce the desired result. Do I have to do this using `diag()` or `spdiag()`?

Comment: You could use `diag`, but you can also remove the loop over `j`, since `j==i` for the diagonal elements (ie index `C(i,i)`. `isdiag` doesn’t check if an index is on the diagonal, it checks if the input matrix is a diagonal matrix. Please read the documentation to the functions you use!

Comment: Yeah I guess the nested looping is unnecessary.  I tried this: https://ibb.co/y59qHLb  I got the equation for ```index``` from: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/409399-modify-only-the-diagonal-entries-in-a-matrix. This still doesn't work for some reason. @CrisLuengo

Comment: Don’t complicate things. Just `for i=1:N, C(i,i) = c(i) + c(i+1); end`.

Comment: When you do `C(index)=…` you’re overwriting all diagonal elements, not just the one at `C(i,i)`.

Comment: I have a bad tendency of overcomplicating. @CrisLuengo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish, you can do this in a single expression simply by using `diag` on the vector of the sum of the adjacent elements, like this:

```matlab
>> C = diag(c(1:end-1) + c(2:end))
C =
    36     0     0
     0    22     0
     0     0    22
```